# How to debug the cuda kernel properly?

Tags: c, cuda, gdb, kernel, cuda-gdb

I have this function:

```c
void initializeCudaMatrixWithCPUMatrix(float *hostA, float *cudaA, int n,
                                       int m) {
  // float testt = hostA[888];
  cudaMalloc((void **)&cudaA, n * m * sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpy(cudaA, hostA, n * m * sizeof(float), 
  cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  // testt = cudaA[888];
}
```

I call it like this:

```c
  initializeCudaMatrixWithCPUMatrix(model->embeddingMatrix,
                                    model->embeddingMatrixCuda, 408, 1024);
```

broadcastedMatrix is malloced like this: (I changed it to that after einpoklum's answer it had the same mistake, he mentioned, before)

```c
  float *broadcastedEmbeddingMatrix;
  gpuMallocMatrix(&broadcastedEmbeddingMatrix, trademodel->maxnum * 128, 1024);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

```c
void gpuMallocMatrix(float **A, int m, int n) {
  cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)A, n * m * sizeof(float));
}
```

Then I call:

```c
broadcastMatrix(trademodel->embeddingMatrixCuda, 
                broadcastedEmbeddingMatrix, 408, 1024, 128);
```

and then in a seperate file I have:

```c
extern "C" void broadcastMatrix( float *Matrix, float *BroadcastedMatrix,
                                 int rows, int cols, int batchsize )   {   
    dim3 rows2d(rows, batchsize);
    broadcastMatrixKernel<<<rows2d, cols>>>(Matrix, BroadcastedMatrix,
                                            rows, cols, batchsize); 
}
```

And then in that file as well the kernel itself:

```
__global__ void broadcastMatrixKernel(float *Matrix, float *BroadcastedMatrix, 
                                      int rows, int cols, int batchsize) {
   int rowIdx = blockIdx.x;
   int batchIdx = blockIdx.y;
   int colIdx = threadIdx.x;
   if (rowIdx < rows && colIdx < cols && batchIdx < batchsize) { 
       BroadcastedMatrix[batchIdx * rows * cols + rowIdx * cols + colIdx] = 
       Matrix[rowIdx * cols + colIdx];   
   }
}
```

And I get: `received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_14, Warp Illegal Address` for this call right here:

```c
broadcastMatrix(trademodel->embeddingMatrixCuda, 
                broadcastedEmbeddingMatrix, 408, 1024, 128);
```

I thought that maybe one of those matrixes were empty thats why I wanted to check with testt = cudaA[888]; Since this doesnt work I put comments now to clarify that its not really part of the code.

@paleonix I use cuda-gdb (or maybe just gdb? I can't look it up atm) with a launch.json and vscode for debugging so I can use breakpoints etc. But if I step into the kernel function itself it doesnt work as I'd expect. It also doesnt happen for the same block/thread pair everytime. Its usually block (0,0,0) thread (418,0,0) or sth (480, 0, 0) or (416, 0, 0) but it happens within the same (the first) block just the thread varies. Maybe I could show you the launch.json and we could fix the debugging. I'd massivly prefer a proper launch.json (i.e. proper debugging within the kernel) over printf statements.

Some additional information: Cuda must be installed correctly since just before the warp error I call another kernel and that one works.
`BroadcastedMatrix` is initialiced with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMalloc` returns `cudaSuccess` for that call so I think thats not the issue. (`cudaMalloc` also returns `cudaSuccess` when mallocing `embeddingMatrixCuda`)

I hope this question makes sense, best regards :)

Comment: You can use `printf` in device code to check variables. `cuda-gdb` is another option, but more complicated.

Comment: Also see [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/10107454).

Comment: @paleonix I edited the question maybe you could have a look at it. I can check the launch.json I have later if I have gdb or gdb-cuda in there.

Comment: @bievjucs Ah, so you are using VS Code. In that case you might be able to use the Nsight plugin which wraps `cuda-gdb` to give you GUI debugging.

Comment: In case of such a device-side illegal access I would run with `compute-sanitizer` (which uses its `memcheck` tool by default). If you compile with `-lineinfo` it should tell you exactly which line (maybe not so interesting here) and what kind of access (read or write) is going wrong.

Comment: With such a memory access violation the values in `cudaA`/`Matrix` are not really of interest because some other address is accessed. Please include the code for the allocation of `BroadcastedMatrix`. You say that the allocation succeeded but it could just be too small. Maybe you forgot a `sizeof(float)` in the call to `cudaMalloc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaking the device-side allocation in `initializeCudaMatrixWithCPUMatrix`:  you're letting `cudaMalloc()` set the value of `cudaA` - which is a local `float*` variable, not a reference to an external `float*`; the variable ceases to exist when returning from the function.

So, when you make your call of the function:

```
initializeCudaMatrixWithCPUMatrix(
    model->embeddingMatrix, model->embeddingMatrixCuda, 408, 1024);
```

the value of `model->embeddingMatrixCuda` remains the same after the function returns.

As for everything happening later in your code - I suggest start with getting your allocation right; then if you're having trouble, maybe ask another question, and make it very focused please.

---

Some more advice, beyond your specific question:

1. Consider having your functions take a GPU ID, since - who knows whether your code is going to be  using the first/default GPU always?
2. (As @paleonix has also suggested:) Always check your API calls for errors. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/10107454) about how to do that conveniently.
3. Even if you're writing C-style rather than C++-style code - consider structuring your data better. So, if you use matrices, define something like:

   ```
   struct matrix {
      float* data;
      size_t dims[2]; // dims[0] is the major dimension
   };
   ```

   And then you could write a function such as:

   ```
   struct matrix create_gpu_copy_of_matrix(struct matrix on_host);
   ```

   and explain in a comment that the returned matrix is "owning", i.e. that it's the caller's responsibility to manage its GPU-side memory. You might then be able to write something like:

   ```
   model->embedding[GPU_DEVICE_SIDE] = create_gpu_copy_of_matrix(
       model->embedding[HOST_SIDE], chosen_gpu_id);
   ```

   within even having to repeat the matrix dimensions; without the possibility of getting them wrong; and with much better readability IMNSHO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I cant really follow your aditional advice. When I started I thought about making a matrix struct but decided against it I dont really remember why. The whole model is a struct though and each matrix is a member as a normal float pointer. Anyway its a one person project so readibility for other people is not that high on my priority list atm. I will keep it in mind though for the future.
For the error, I added the mallocing of the broadcastedMatrix to my question. I had to change it aswell since it had the same error you described. Is it good like that now?

Comment: I changed the signature:

`void initializeCudaMatrixWithCPUMatrix(float *hostA, float** cudaA, int n, int m) {
  cudaMalloc((void **)cudaA, n * m * sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpy(*cudaA, hostA, n * m * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}`

and the call to this:

`initializeCudaMatrixWithCPUMatrix(model->embeddingMatrix, &(model->embeddingMatrixCuda), 408, 1024);`
It had an effect. I still get the warp error but only in the (361, 3, 1) - (96,0,0) block - thread pair. Is it correct this way?

Comment: Point 1. I do know that but anyway thanks for the advice because maybe I will work more with gpus or with other people on this kind of things in the future.

Comment: @bievjucs: On StackOverflow, answers regard the questions as asked. Questions may be edited for clarification, to increase focus, to improve formatting or correct typos - but this is not supposed to be an interactive exchange. As for my additional advice - it is just a general suggestion, based on what the beginning of your answer looks like. Adopt it only if you find it useful.

Comment: Well ok. Thanks. I just would like a bit more information on "leaking the device-side allocation" and if my changes fixed this.

Comment: @bievjucs Yes, a `float**` is the way around that particular problem in C. Feel free to open a new question with the new error but maybe start by creating a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Often one can find the issue just by trying to create an MRE.